# Why do the carbonyl oxygens in EDTA not participate in coordination?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds

I recently had two, very brief lectures on coordination compounds. In those lectures, my teacher mentioned EDTA because of its importance in analytical chemistry and its very stable complexes and mentioned it is a hexadentate ligand after the removal of the 4 hydrogens from the carboxylic acid groups, the other two bonds coming from the nitrogen bonds.

My question is why do the carbonyl oxygens not participate in coordination even though they have two lone pairs of electrons. I suppose it is because of the closeness of the carbonylic oxygen atoms and the nitrogen atoms, because if the two of them bonded via electron pair donation, the bonds would be too close to each other and would create instability in the structure. Is that correct? If yes, why does the nitrogen atom donate instead of the oxygen atom?

Comment: Having two oxygen atoms attach to both the same carbon and the same metal atom is a four-membered ring, not best.

Comment: Now, Oscar answered question "Why not both oxygens of carboxylic group bind?" Which is a pretty good one, and sometimes they do. If you'd ask why "carbonylic" one doesn't bind instead of the other, it's not a good one - both oxygens in uncoordinated carboxylate group are the same.